# Java web service consumable in java app but not in android app

Tags: java, android, web-services, noclassdeffounderror

As shown in below screenshot, I have created a web service(in java) and a client application(android app) by following [this article](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html).

I also got *BUILD SUCCESSFUL* message after creating *Ant build file* under section **Create a web service client** in article and under client app 8 files are generated as shown in image(2) below.

Now when I write `HelloWebService service = new HelloWebService();` in client app, app crashes and I get following exception: 
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.service.client.HelloWebService**

**But** If I try to consume same web service in a java app as following, it works:

```
HelloWebService service = new HelloWebService();
com.myservice.service.client.HelloWeb helloWeb = service.getHelloWebPort();
String response = helloWeb.sayGreeting(input);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Any help appreciated.

---

[image: screenshot]

### Edit (1)

Although I'm using the similar command for both apps to generate required web services java files, the structure is different for both apps. In android app, the files are getting generated under **xml** directory.

Command is : `wsimport -keep -s C:\Android\workspace\WebServiceDemo\src -p com.mycompany.service.client http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb?wsdl`

[image: screenshot]

### Edit (2)

**HelloWebService.java**

```
package com.mycompany.service.client;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "HelloWebService", targetNamespace = "http://service.mycompany.com/", wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb?wsdl")
public class HelloWebService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL HELLOWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(com.mycompany.service.client.HelloWebService.class.getName());

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = com.mycompany.service.client.HelloWebService.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: 'http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb?wsdl', retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        HELLOWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public HelloWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public HelloWebService() {
        super(HELLOWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://service.mycompany.com/", "HelloWebService"));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns HelloWeb
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "HelloWebPort")
    public HelloWeb getHelloWebPort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://service.mycompany.com/", "HelloWebPort"), HelloWeb.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns HelloWeb
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "HelloWebPort")
    public HelloWeb getHelloWebPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://service.mycompany.com/", "HelloWebPort"), HelloWeb.class, features);
    }

}
```

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webservicedemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.webservicedemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you ported the service on a public IP? Or when you run your app then this service should be running on your local browser I mean it should be up.

Comment: Yeah, it's running and thats why I'm able to consume it in Java app but not in android app :(

Comment: You shoud post the android code that is calling this web service. Also you have to set `INTERNET`permission access in your android-manifest.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned Internet permission. Code in android app to consume web service is exactly similar to what I have used for java app(written in question). Please check edited question.

Comment: is there any lib that you are forget to add in build path, next thing what a `hellowebservice.java` are extend ? simple class or extend some parent class ?

Comment: @chintankhetiya: you are talking sense I guess as I found this is in my log-cat: **Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mycompany/service/client/HelloWebService; Link of class 'Lcom/mycompany/service/client/HelloWebService;' failed**

Comment: parent class is *Service* and I could see this line in `HelloWebService` of both app: `import javax.xml.ws.Service;`

Comment: can you please show me your `HelloWebService` file and manifest

Comment: `<service android:name=".HelloWebService" android:enabled="true" />` add in manifest before `application` tag and get back to me

Comment: `service` tag is not allowed before application. So I added it as direct child of application tag but same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I gave up this approach after learning that `javax.*` packages are not supported in Android.

I used something similar to this:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String add = "{\"MemberNo\":\"" + uri[0] + "\"}";
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(wsdl);// + add
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            postMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(add);
            postMethod.setEntity(entity);
            response = httpclient.execute(postMethod);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else {
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseString;
    }
  }
```

Thanks all for your time and response !